# W3 Document Object Model Range offsets when having mixed content

Tags: range, w3c

If I have a text element with a strong child element within its text.
For example:

```
<p>abcd<strong>ef</strong>gh</p>
```

What would be the correct end offset value for a range that ends between g and h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range's `endContainer` property would be the text node whose content is "gh" and `endOffset` property 1.

Further reading:

- The spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-range
- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range

Comment: Is that an implicit node that I should expect every tool parsing the html above to generate? Since the <p> one contains more than just gh.

Comment: @SopKillen: Any DOM parser will produce that node, yes. The `p` element will have three child nodes: a text node with text "abcd", a `strong` element and a text node with text "gh".

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot!